# I am trying to install check-jsonschema in my azure DevOps pipeline using bash script with command pip3 install check-jsonschema

Tags: python, azure-devops, pip

I am trying to install check-jsonschema in my azure DevOps pipeline using bash script with command pip3 install check-jsonschema

I am getting the error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-u48i45ec/ruamel-yaml-clib_2a15479bb22c491b8ba675f78470fa73/setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bpnbewqf']
      test compiling /tmp/tmp_ruamel_fh9vi6iq/test_ruamel_yaml.c -> test_ruamel_yaml compile error: /tmp/tmp_ruamel_fh9vi6iq/test_ruamel_yaml.c
      Exception: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Micrsoft hosted ubuntu agent, pip3 install check-jsonschema could run well.

For self-hosted agent, it seems that you need to install GCC.
You could check GCC version with cmd:

```
gcc --version
```

If it failed, you could try
Method1:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

Method2:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

The second method is to install build-essentials onto your system which will also include the gcc.

Comment: I am using docker container with alpine operating system and running the jobs on the container and tried to install gcc on alpine using apk install build-essential. The job got error  with the below message DEPRECATION: ruamel.yaml.clib is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559